# Can I have a contact entry with a wildcard phone number?

Tags: contacts

my office desk phone forwards to my Android mobile phone, using the original caller ID. This means that I receive calls from number like 01200 000001, 01200 000002, 01200 000003, 01200 000004 - etc, where just the last few digits change (depending on the extension that is calling me).

Is there a way to define a contact with a phone number like 01200 000*** - so it appears on my phone as a contact called "Office"?

Comment: aww, I just saw this; https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13243

Comment: Yeah, something they love to do recently: first having it lying around for 3+ years (this one dates back to 2011), and then closing as "obsolete". Many issues I've starred endet up this way – oh, and at the very same time... Hint: Some [CallerID apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_callerid) might support this. Not tested, but worth a look I'd say.